# VBA Selecting Array Values Between Specified Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck on the following problem:

I have created a `VBA Excel Userform` that calculates the `max` and `min` hole size for a given bolt size.

All calculations etc are contained within the code on the form, I have not and do not want to reference a spreadsheet.

I’ve added a Combobox to list all suitable standard drill sizes that fall between the maximum and minimum hole sizes but I want it to show only the ones suitable as to not have a hole too large or too small.

Example:

For M12 Bolt with 0.25mm Tolerance

```
MaxHoleSizeBox = 12.3
MinHoleSizeBox = 11.41
```

From 10mm and up the drill sizes increase in steps of 0.5mm, therefore:

```
Suitable Drill Sizes = 11.5mm and 12mm
```

Note that drill sizes up to 10mm increase in steps of 0.1mm while drill sizes above 10mm increase in steps of 0.5mm as shown in the Array below.

What I have so far:

```
Private Sub MinHoleSize_Change()

On Error Resume Next

'Array List of Standard Drill Sizes

arrList = Array(5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17, 17.5, 18, 18.5, 19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 24, 24.5, 25, 25.5, 26, 26.5, 27, 27.5, 28, 28.5, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.5, 31, 31.5, 32, 32.5, 33, 33.5, 34, 34.5, 35, 35.5, 36, 36.5, 37, 37.5, 38)

DrillBox.List = arrList

End Sub
```

How can I populate the ComboBox with only the standard drill sizes from the Array that fall between the max and min specified hole size?

```
Private Sub MinHoleSize_Change()
On Error Resume Next
'Array List of Standard Drill Sizes

arrList = Array(5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17, 17.5, 18, 18.5, 19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 24, 24.5, 25, 25.5, 26, 26.5, 27, 27.5, 28, 28.5, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.5, 31, 31.5, 32, 32.5, 33, 33.5, 34, 34.5, 35, 35.5, 36, 36.5, 37, 37.5, 38)

DrillBox.List = arrList

End Sub
```

I would like the combobox to update to show only the suitable drill sizes.

Comment: You could try for loop and if else to complete your demand. Also we usually ask question here when you facing problem at coding. We won't ask how to do a whole function and so on like this. Just a bit suggestion. Hoping it is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am a beginner and have learnt how to write the rest of the code on my own. I just can't figure out how to do this last part to complete my application. I have done a lot of searching around and trial and error trying to solve it but I can't find out how to do it so as a last resort I am asking for assistance to complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub MinHoleSize_Change()
On Error Resume Next
arrList = Array(5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17, 17.5, 18, 18.5, 19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 24, 24.5, 25, 25.5, 26, 26.5, 27, 27.5, 28, 28.5, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.5, 31, 31.5, 32, 32.5, 33, 33.5, 34, 34.5, 35, 35.5, 36, 36.5, 37, 37.5, 38)
```

Dim i As Variant

```
For Each i In arrList
      If i>=MinHoleSizeBox And i<=MaxHoleSizeBox Then
                YourCombobox.AddItem (i)
            End If
        Next

End Sub
```

This just a prototype. Hoping it can help you.

References:

[How to use ComBoxbox](http://checktechno.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-use-combobox.html)

[For-Each](https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-each-vbnet)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have slightly tweaked your suggested code as follows to get it working.

'Private Sub MinDiaBox_Change()

On Error Resume Next

'List of standard drill sizes
arrList = Array(5, 5.1, ........ 37, 37.5, 38)

Dim i As Variant

For Each i In arrList
      If i >= MinHoleSizeBox And i <= MaxHoleSizeBox Then
                DrillBox.AddItem (i)
            End If
        Next i

End Sub'